# Ionic Angular ion-img and fallback image issue

Tags: html, angular, image, ionic-framework

I am building a mobile app using Ionic Angular framework and want to support `webp` images as primary images and if it is not supported I want the fallback image to be displayed.

It works with `img`

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="assets/images/hello.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <img src="assets/images/hello.png" alt="Hello image" />
</picture>
```

But it does not work with `ion-img`. It always shows the fallback png image here.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="assets/images/hello.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <ion-img src="assets/images/hello.png" alt="Hello image"></ion-img>
</picture>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let's see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) about `<picture>` tag:

> The  HTML element contains zero or more  elements and
> one  element to offer alternative versions of an image for
> different display/device scenarios.

`<picture>` should contain only `<source>` and `<img>` tags but not `<ion-img>`. Additionally, `<ion-img>` more complicated element then `<img>`: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/img

So, you should use this code in your project:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="assets/images/hello.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <img src="assets/images/hello.png" alt="Hello image" />
</picture>
```